# QEMU run OK by Eclipse but fail when debugging

Tags: linux, eclipse, qemu

I am investigating the source code for QEMU.

I opened it with Eclipse and configured the environment. Then I can build it for the ARM platform and run it by booting Linux.

When debugging, **it fails after running through some functions**.
The error message is:

```
qemu: could not open disk image rdinit=/bin/sh": No such file or directory
```

Comment: It looks like QEMU tries to use your host's `/bin/sh` without architecture checks. Try to grab an already compiled binary of `sh` for your target platform on the internet (`busybox` renamed to `sh` will run fine) and use it with QEMU

Comment: Using Eclipse, QEMU can boot Linux with busybox as file system. However, error occurs when I debug QEMU in the same environment. That is weird because if I can run QEMU, I will be able to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there's missing `"` (double quote character) somewhere in project configuration files, or, maybe, a redundant one.

a typical QEMU invocation is `qemu-system-arm -kernel path/to/zImage -initrd path/to/test_rootfs -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/test"`

if you skip first double quote just after `-append` - qemu will think that `rdinit=/test` is a disk image, and try to open it as a file

one possible solution is to grep your eclipse project dir for `"rdinit"` keyword and examine all grep results for missing/redundant quotes

```
cd /your/project/dir
grep -rw rdinit .
```

Comment: This is my command:
-M versatilepb -kernel zImage -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/bin/sh"
So I don`t forget the double quote after -append.
I don`t think something is wrong in the command because QEMU can run  successfully. 
It only fails when debugging.

Comment: what happens when you are debugging? maybe debugger loses a quote? maybe you can use `strace` to see what command being invoked?

Comment: When debugging, QEMU fails at the function static int parse_block_error_action(const char *buf, int is_read), and output error message:
qemu: could not open disk image rdinit=/bin/sh: No such file or directory